# Evolution adds new line after each line in previous message on reply and forwarding

Tags: linux, email, outlook

I'm using evolution email client with Exchange Server.
When I replying to message or forwarding, previous message changes: after each line appears new empty line.

```
Hi?
How are you?
```

becomes

```
Hi?

How are you?
```

It seems, that it's appears only when original message was written in Outlook (or when Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64).

When I replying on thread again, only new mails change.

I'm using Fedora 20 x64. Evolution version: 3.10.4

link on letters: https://yadi.sk/d/hm7QJuNqcqnjM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got response in [evolution mail list](http://gnome-evolution-general.1774414.n4.nabble.com/Evolution-adds-new-line-after-each-line-in-previous-message-on-reply-and-forwarding-tp4660168p4660170.html):

> Hi, this is a known issue and you can find some bug reports on this if you search the evolution bugzilla. This is due to the gtkhtml element used in earlier Evolution versions. There's a new webkit based editor in the last versions (ie 3.13.8). Although this works well, we are generally recommended by developers to wait for 3.14 series. If you know how to compile Evolution yourself, you can give it a try.

It's known bug, repaired since 3.13.8 version.